# comment didn't live refresh

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, live-refresh

Comment didn't appear until I commented:

[image]

As soon as I commented the older comment appeared out of nowhere, very annoying.

Using FireFox 25.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had disabled live updates while doing a major deployment.  It should be back on now.